# SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'for' in I:\Complete Web Development Course\EJS\To Do List\views\list.ejs while compiling ejs

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have been trying this create a to do list using ejs and applying it in html.
But Failing to get the result.

CODE Snippet:

```
<ul>
    <li>Food Items</li>
    <li>Play Cricket</li>
    <li>Learn To code</li>
    <li>Apply for jobs</li>
    <li>Play game of Chess</li>
  <% for(int i = 0;i<new_item.length;i++) %>
    <% { %>
    <li>  <%= new_item %> </li>
  <% } %>
  </ul>
```

Error Getting:

```
    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in I:\Complete Web Development Course\EJS\To Do List\views\list.ejs while compiling ejs

If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass `async: true` as an option.
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at Template.compile (I:\Complete Web Development Course\EJS\To Do List\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:673:12)
    at Object.compile (I:\Complete Web Development Course\EJS\To Do List\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:398:16)
    at handleCache (I:\Complete Web Development Course\EJS\To Do List\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:235:18)
    at tryHandleCache (I:\Complete Web Development Course\EJS\To Do List\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:274:16)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (I:\Complete Web Development Course\EJS\To Do List\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:491:10)
    at View.render (I:\Complete Web Development Course\EJS\To Do List\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (I:\Complete Web Development Course\EJS\To Do List\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:657:10)
    at Function.render (I:\Complete Web Development Course\EJS\To Do List\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:609:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (I:\Complete Web Development Course\EJS\To Do List\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1039:7)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
for(int i = 0;i<new_item.length;i++)
```

`int` is not a valid type declaration in ejs so you should use `let` or `var` instead.